# SQL and Entityframework, can't get the result I want

Tags: sql, entity-framework-4

I have 2 questions, one about SQL and one about Entity Framework:

I have a table "UserSet" with all information about the user; and I have the table "FriendRequests", that handles UserID and FriendID information. My current user is "rugardini". I need to list the Friends requests. So, I did a query like this only for testing purposes:

```
select fq.FriendID, u.Nickname from 
FriendRequestsSet as fq, UserSet as u 
where fq.UserID=16
```

But my result is like this:

```
| FriendID | Nickname |
------------------------
|   17     |rugardini |
|   17     |  Teste   |
```

== edited ====================

Now I realize my query should be:

```
SELECT u.ID, u.Nickname
FROM UserSet as u, FriendRequestsSet as f
WHERE u.ID=f.FriendID
ORDER BY u.ID
```

I'm getting the right result ^^ I still need to know how to "translate" it to EF4.1?

Answer (score 0):

Rubia in Linq its almost similar

```
    from u in USerSet
    join f in FriendRequestsSet
    on u.ID=f.FriendID
    ORDERBY u.ID
    select new {u.ID,u.Nickname}
```

Comment: Thank you Amritpal, do you have any example how I could use this code  in the MVC?

Answer (score 0):

for using this query you would like to use different column from each table to create a new view (as we do in sqlserver). We need to create a Viewmodel in MVC that will represent columns

```cs
     public class FriendRequest
         {
              int col1{get;set;}
              int col2{get;set;}
              //Here comes the Column You Want To Consider For your View Model
         }

      var list=from u in USerSet
         join f in FriendRequestsSet
         on u.ID=f.FriendID
         ORDERBY u.ID
         select new FriendResquest{Col1=u.ID,col2=u.Nickname}
         //Here by map your columns as declared in your view model
```